# How to make popup menu like this using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my application and I want to implement popup menu like the below image, having a logo and respective text.

Please help me to achieve this, any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is.This is actually done in the app which you posted screenshot for.I think you are familiar with ActionbarSherlok.The button for this dropdown menu will be on actionbar.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Used to put dark icons on light action bar


    SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("");



    subMenu1.add("Item1").setIcon(R.drawable.icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {





                    return false;
                }
            });

    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
    subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark);
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This does work. Also, if you want the menu to appear as a regular button in the action bar, you can do this:

    subMenu1.setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    subMenu1.getItem().setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)

Answer (score 1):

Added `PopupMenu` in [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/mihirjoshi21/ActionBarSherlock).